Pandas добавление списка в ячейку
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно добавить через pandas столбец в датафрейм, который будет содержать в 1 ячейке список.
Допустим создадим Датафрейм
test1 = DataFrame({'Name': [1, 2, 3], 'Family': [1, 2, 3]})
lst = [1,2,3]


Необходимо чтобы получилось так:

И есть ли возможность добавить сразу несколько списков в 1 ячейку?

Еще варианты
test1['number'] = test1.assign(number=None).number.map({None: lst})

и
test1['number'] = test1.apply(lambda x: lst, axis=1)


Выглядит не очень красиво и не очень понятно зачем это, но можно сделать список списков:
test1['Number'] = [lst]*len(test1)

Несколько списков в одной ячейке - делаем список списков списков:
lst = [1,2,3]
lst2 = [4,5,6]
test1['Number'] = [[lst, lst2]]*len(test1)


Спасибо! Задача стояла к 1 наименования кинуть разных поставщиков. И единственное что пришло мне в голову, это залить поставщиков в лист, закинуть в столбец и выполнить explode по столбцу поставщиков.
